# I got this error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "

Tags: android

Basically I got this error when I try to convert String to int and when there isn't any string I got problem but still "" should be null, or "" and I can't Handle it.
As an example I want to create contacts that only has two fields name and age, but only name is important for me.

```
public class Contact {

public String name;
public int age;

public Contact(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Contact() {

}
 public Contact(String name,int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age=age
}
```

}

in the part of code for some reason I need user add new Contact and its not important to insert age.
after user submit I expect get new Contact.

```
EditText editName=findviewByid(r.id.edit_name);
EditText editAge=findviewByid(r.id.edit_age);
.
.
.
```

when user click the submit button :

```
String name = editName.getText().toString().trim();

String age = editAge.getText().toString().trim();

Contact contact =new (name,Integer.parseInt(age));
```

if user didn't input age we got this error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Comment: You have to check `empty` also as `empty` is not a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct as per how `parseInt` works. You have to check the value you received from the text view for `null` or `empty`. You could do something like this:

```
String name = editName.getText().toString().trim();
String age = editAge.getText().toString().trim();

// You have to think about what value you want to give to your `age` variable in
// the case of `null`. This depends on you, I have given it a value of -1 just for
// demonstration. You also need to make sure that you only allow numeric input in 
// your text field, or otherwise you need to make sure you can cast the provided 
// input to an integer before using `parseInt`
int ageInt = !TextUtils.isEmpty(age) ? Integer.parseInt(age) : -1
Contact contact =new (name, ageInt);
```

Comment: Thank you ,it works , before i tried to fix like this if( age !=null) { int ageInt=Integer.parseInt(age)}else{int ageInt=0}; but  got error like before.

Comment: I made a small edit which was to send `ageInt` instead of the `age` parameter in the `Contact` constructor. Hopefully it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because of how Integer.parseInt works.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)):

> parseInt
>
> Added in API level 1 public static int parseInt (String s)
>
> Parses the
> string argument as a signed decimal integer.
>
> The characters in the
> string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may
> be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or
> an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value.
>
> The
> resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and
> the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String,
> int) method.
>
> Parameters s  String: a String containing the int representation to be
> parsed
>
> Returns int    the integer value represented by the argument in
> decimal.
>
> **Throws NumberFormatException if the string does not contain a
> parsable integer.**

You MUST pass a string with a number in it to parseInt.

Comment: thanks , you are right , but when the user didn't enter any digit how can i handle it  in the case that i don't want to force user to enter anything